# Почему imagecreatefromwebp не понимает переменную?

Tags: php

```
$im = imagecreatefromwebp('site.com/pic.webp');
```

Такой код работает, но если сделать вот так

```
$pic1 = $a[0]->src;
$im = imagecreatefromwebp($pic1);
```

Уже не работает. Чего оно так? В пременной $pic1 ссылка имеется.

Comment: Содержимое `$pic1` выведите на экран так `echo "'$pic1'";`.

Comment: 'site.com/pic.webp'

Comment: А если там будет `http://site.com/pic.webp` тоже не будет работать?

Comment: Вообще-то у меня $im = imagecreatefromwebp('http ://site.com/pic.webp'); но разве это имеет значение?

Comment: @emtecif, Ситуация, когда замена строкового литерала на переменную с тем же значением приводит к неработоспособности кода попахивает магией. Похоже, что у вас есть ошибка где-то еще.

Comment: Кстати, а какие ошибки выдает PHP? И почему вы решили, что код не работает?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, но ведь если использовать ссылку на прямую, то работает.

Comment: Никаких ошибок не выдает.

Comment: Эта запись 'site.com/pic.webp' ссылкой не является, протокол не указан.

Comment: Потому что если if($im) echo "1"; единицы я не вижу, да код дальше должен изменить формат на *.jpg, а он этого не делает, но если вставить ссылку на прямую, то работает

Comment: @Visman, у меня там ссылка https://...

Comment: Ясно теперь, а то из вашего вопроса этого не видно.

Comment: Лог ошибок сервера посмотрите даже если у вас на экране нет ошибок.

Comment: Последние записи давно были в файле /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Есть еще может варианты как это сделать?)

Comment: @emtecif, разбирайтесь с подавлением сообщений об ошибках. Это все, что можно посоветовать на данном этапе.

Comment: как кстати включить чтоб ошибки вьіводились в файл? debian 7